# firebase Http function error

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, axios

I have written a Firebase Http function.
When successful it returns status 200 with some data.
When it errors I want the client (which is using axios.post) to use a standard error handler which means showing the `error.message` property.

If I send an error code back with data - yes, I can access that data/message etc in `error.response.data`, but that isn't a pattern I can use for all errors - some errors might occur that don't give a response or data property.

So if I just want to access error.message at the client I need to be able to set that message but at the moment if I use for example:-

```
res.status(520).send('My custom error message')
```

I get:

> Request failed with status 520

in the error.message, then I have to go to the error.response.data to get the actual message I want to display.

How could I do this so that I just use `error.message` regardless? I have tried using

```
res.status(x).send({error:customerror})
```

also tried

```
res.statusText = customerror
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on Axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), you have to use the error.response to get info from your custom message. You wouldn't be able to set the value on error.message on Axios.
If you really need to use error.message, you have to make a custom function to change it on cliente.

Comment: Well actually it is a block of code that first checks if error.response and then goes on to check other possible errors (error.request) and that's what my question was trying to avoid. I was hoping that error.message would at least hold the message in all cases and that I could set that message from the server.